# Today's Sales report from returning customers VS new customers

Tags: mysql, subquery

Below is my query for Todays sales report which is working perfectly

```
SELECT SUM( total_price ) AS total FROM basket LEFT JOIN `orders` ON basket.order_id=orders.order_id WHERE orders.date_added BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
```

Now I need another query to know how much of today's sales is coming from Returning customers ( I have Mobile column in Orders table which is unique per customer and we can rely on that to know if this customer has previous purchase record or not)

Let me explain why I have to use mobile column , my database does not have customers table which is usual in e-commerce platforms, normal scenario is that there is customers table with unique customer_id column, so this customer_id should be used in Orders table to assign an order to a customer. In my platform as I don't have this column the only way to understand if the customer is new or returning is to check his full_name or mobile number in Orders table, if there is a record from past days so it means the customer is repeated, if there is no record for his name or mobile it means customer is new

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that `Mobile` column contains but it works like this with a conditional aggregation

```
SELECT SUM( total_price ) AS total,
       SUM(case when Mobile is not null then total_price else 0 end ) AS fromReturning
FROM basket
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON basket.order_id=orders.order_id 
WHERE country='ae' 
AND orders.date_added BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 day) 
AND orders.delivery_status <> -1
```

Comment: Mobile column is customer mobile number in Order table which is like below,
order_id, full_name, mobile, address, ....

I think there is misunderstanding from your side :)

Comment: So if the column is filled with something he is a returning customer. I updated the query.

Comment: Or let's make it easier, suppose I have customer_id in Orders table which is unique ( please forget about mobile column )

Comment: Let me explain why I have to use mobile column , my database does not have customers table which is usual in e-commerce platforms, normal scenario is that there is customers table with unique customer_id column, so this customer_id should be used in Orders table to assign an order to a customer.
In my platform as I don't have this column the only way to understand if the customer is new or returning is to check his full_name or mobile number, if it's registered before so it means the customer is repeated, if there is no record for his name or mobile it means customer is new